# Omnigraffle: deleting one object also deletes another (apparently unconnected) object

Tags: omnigraffle

I have one box (b1) "inside" (ie, in front of, and smaller than) another (b2). If I move the inner box, the outer one also moves (in a rather strange way). If I delete the inner box, the outer one is deleted too. They're not grouped. Is this at all expected behaviour, or a bug?

(To add some more context which might explain it, the inner box (b1) is connected by an arrow to another box (b3). Deleting the arrow deletes b2 and b3. Deleting b3 deletes b2 and the arrow. Deleting b1 deletes b2, b3 and the arrow.)

*Oh, I get it: my diagram is, strangely enough, a hierarchical one, although it looks nothing like it. b1 is obviously the parent of the other objects.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the question, the cause of this strange behaviour is that the diagram is obviously of a hierarchical type. Now the question is whether it can be converted to a non-hierarchical one.